# Finding a set of related items in Django

Tags: django

In Django, I am using the following code to get images related to a Location from the LocationImage model.

```
{% for location in locations %}
{% for image in location.locationimage_set.all %}
etc
```

If that location is a region, and there are no images for that region, I want to be able to get images for cities in that region, by still referring to only that region.

cities are also part of the location model, with a region field set to the region and related_name='location_region'

Any ideas on how to do this?

For example, if I had a region field in my LocationImage model, how would I refer to a set of all LocationImages with that region id in the region field, not in the main id field.

As requested, models:

```
class LocationImage(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    imagelink = models.URLField(max_length=500, null=True)

class Location(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, verbose_name="ascii name")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    locationtype = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    region = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='location_region')
    country = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='location_country')
```

where locationtype = 'city', 'region or 'country'

Comment: Show the code of you models, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [{% for %} ... {% empty %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty) template tag.

```
{% for location in locations %}
    {% for image in location.locationimage_set.all %}
        ...
    {% empty %}
        {# there is no images for `location` #}
        {% ifequal location.locationtype 'region' %}
            {% for city in location.location_region.all %}
                {% for image in city.locationimage_set.all %}
                    ...
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endifequal %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But I think this is too complex template code.  May be it will be better to add `get_images()` method to the `Location` model and implement this logic in python?

```
class Location(models.Model):

    def get_images(self):
        images = self.locationimage_set.all()
        if self.locationtype == 'region' and not images:
            images = LocationImage.objects.filter(location__region=self)
        return images
```

This method is much more efficient than the template version.  And the template will be as simple as:

```
{% for location in locations %}
    {% for image in location.get_images %}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is awesome! I went for the get_images method and that worked. Took a little bit of re-jigging of my code to match, but that worked well!!